# PHP parsing XML data

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I am parsing an xml file successfully in PHP, but having difficulty parsing a specific entry trying to output a table.

My xml is as follow

```
<OutputData Name="ExchangeRate" ContentTypeID="">
    <DataTitle>Exchange</DataTitle>
    <DataInfo>
        <TABLE CLASS="DataTable">
            <TR><TD>1.00 GBP = 1.68 ALL</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD>1.00 USD = 1.58 ALL</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD>1.00 EUR = 1.35 ALL</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD>Currency conversion rates as of  January 2012</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>
    </DataInfo>
</OutputData>
```

if I try to output it this way
`$info = $outputinfo->DataInfo;`
I am getting an error.

any help?

My code is as follow

```
$xmlfile = $currenttitle.".xml";
$info = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
$region = $country->Region[0]; 
$section = $region->Section;  
if($info){
  foreach ($region->Section as $sectioninfo){
    $title = $sectioninfo->SectionTitle;
    echo "<b>$title</b><br />\n";
    $output = $sectioninfo->OutputData;
    foreach ($sectioninfo->OutputData as $outputinfo){
      $titleinfo = $outputinfo->DataTitle;
      $info = $outputinfo->DataInfo;
    }
  }
```

for the section above, I get the Title display, as Exchange, but the Table is not rendered.

SOLUTION
Thanks to h4b0 who put me in the right direction

```
$rowinfo = $outputinfo->DataInfo->TABLE->TR->TD;
foreach ($outputinfo->DataInfo->TABLE->TR as $rowexchange){
  echo $rowexchange->TD."<br />";
}
```

Comment: What is your code to get `$outputinfo`?

Comment: How are you parsing it?  What is `$outputinfo`?  What error are you getting?

Comment: Without seeing your code we can only guess...  
$info = $outputinfo['DataInfo'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you won't get error if you try `$info = $outputinfo->DataInfo->TABLE->TR->TD`. If I'm wrong, post your error message.

Comment: h4b0, you've point me in the right direction, it seems to be working and retrieving the data using $info = $outputinfo->DataInfo->TABLE->TR->TD, but how to loop through each TR?

Comment: `foreach($outputinfo->DataInfo->TABLE->TR AS $td){}`